# How to edit /etc/hosts file

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2, dns

How to you edit the `/etc/hosts` file? My father put every video site on the internet on and he won't tell me how to get rid of it. I need an answer because tinypic and youtube are on it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need open the file as root:

Open the terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

`sudo nano /etc/hosts` (You need enter your user password)

after, it will open the file to edit, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close and save the file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Get the  info you need your going to want to copy the commands output.

```
neil@ASUS:~$ sudo cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.0.1
```

Copy the outputted code.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   ASUS
```

Then type in terminal

```
sudo rm /etc/hosts
```

then type in

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Then your hosts file shoud look like this.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       ASUS
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to save

That should restore what your father did. unless he deleted 127.0.0.1 from the host file.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Copying things from a file and then inserting it in the same file is really useful...

Comment: @wie5Ooma   I edited my post. just released my mistake.