# Ubuntu(16.04) - virtual Host problem

Tags: networking, server, webserver, ip, virtualhost

I used ubuntu 16.04. I configure virtual host in my system and also working properly on local host- using hostname(turboreceiver) and using ip (192.168.0.56).

when I try this in my other pc in same network

> > using ip(192.168.0.56) in browser in my other pc in same network they show my index.html file.
> >     using hostname(turboreceiver) in browser they are not show my index.html file.

Please suggest me where am I wrong??

Comment: If I understand You correctly You need to map the `turboreceiver` to the ip (on the second pc). You can use the `/etc/hosts` file for that purpose : https://askubuntu.com/questions/691293/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file

Answer (score 0):

The local machine will resolve the hostname via its `/etc/hosts`, since it has a mapping of its own hostname and IP address (usually). Others will need to contact a name server since they are unaware of a host with `turboreceiver` as hostname in their `/etc/hosts`.

The simplest non-automated way is to add a record to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
192.168.0.56    turboreceiver
```

For other ways and better explanation see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname)

Comment: I already try this one. but in other pc when i enter turboreceiver not open index.html file.

Comment: How does your virtualhost config look like? It's locate at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf` most likely.

Comment: thank you for the reply. in my system there is no httpd directory.

Comment: There is no httpd on the server? What webserver are you using? This is what virtual hosting is: ([Virtual Hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based))